# How to configure neovim with update-alternatives for ex view and vimdiff behaviours?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, debian, neovim

Of course, we could create aliases, but then we loose the Debian integration. For instance, the 3 first works, as they are just aliases, but the 3 last fails:

```
NVIM_PATH=/usr/local/bin/nvim
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi "${NVIM_PATH}" 110
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vim vim "${NVIM_PATH}" 110
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor neovim /usr/local/bin/nvim 110
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/view view "${NVIM_PATH}" 110
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vimdiff vimdiff "${NVIM_PATH}" 110
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ex ex "${NVIM_PATH}" 110
```

The view, vimdiff and ex commands just starts nvim normally, instead of respectively read-only, diff, and ex mode.

Why is nvim reacting differently than vim ?
How should we do to keep the update-alternatives integration in Debian/Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/vi 10
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/vim 20
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/nvim 30
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/view 40
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/vimdiff 50
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/ex 60
```

Set the High priority for the preferred editor.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question. There is only _one_ editor (nvim), but it can be called under different names, which should lead to different behavior when called as `view`, `ex` or `vimdiff`.

Answer (score 1):

Make helper scripts in `/usr/bin/` to provide the required functionality.

`sudo nvim /usr/bin/nview`

```
#!/bin/bash

exec nvim -R "$@"
```

`sudo nvim /usr/bin/nvimdiff`

```
#!/bin/bash

exec nvim -d "$@"
```

Make these files executable and install the scripts:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/nview /usr/bin/nvimdiff
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/view view /usr/bin/nview 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vimdiff vimdiff /usr/bin/nvimdiff 100
```

AFAIK, `neovim` does not provide any `ex` mode.

(This is an old question, hopefully, it will help those looking for an answer)

When removing `neovim`, you have to run these manually:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove view /usr/bin/nview
sudo update-alternatives --remove vimdiff /usr/bin/nvimdiff
sudo rm /usr/bin/nview /usr/bin/nvimdiff
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to make neovim provide view in Fedora 39, thank you for the snippets!